# Opening latex files works on one computer but not the other

Tags: auctex, latex, emacsclient

On my primary computer, I have the following set up for emacs and everything works like a charm. I use emacs cvs, auctex cvs, and latexmk on a Ubuntu 14.04. However, I just put the same set up on another computer running Ubuntu 14.04 but LaTeX files are opened in `fundamental-mode`.

[image]

In my init I have:

```
;; Start server and set directory
(setq server-socket-dir (format "/tmp/emacs1000"))
;; Not sure if (useruid) does anything or the difference between
;; (server-start) and '(server-mode t) in custom
;(setq server-socket-dir (format "/tmp/emacs1000" (user-uid)))
;(server-start)

;; Package list M-x package-list-packages
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
         '("marmelade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
         '("elpa" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/"))

;; Package initialize
(package-initialize)

;; AucTex & RefTeX
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/")
(load "auctex.el" nil t t)
(load "preview-latex.el" nil t t)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTex t)
(global-font-lock-mode t)
(setq font-lock-maximum-decoration t)
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master nil)
(setq TeX-save-query nil)

;; Copy and paste between Emac   instances     
(setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
(setq interprogram-paste-function 'x-cut-buffer-or-selection-value)

;; Disablin autosave                                                           
(setq auto-save-default nil)

;; Adjusting tab distance
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 2)

;; Enable Line Numbering
(setq line-number-mode t)
(setq column-number-mode t)

;; Set the fill column
(setq default-fill-column 80)

;; Turn on Auto Fill mode automatically in all modes
;; Auto-fill-mode the the automatic wrapping of lines and insertion of
;; newlines when the cursor goes over the column limit.
;; This should actually turn on auto-fill-mode by default in all major
;; modes. The other way to do this is to turn on the fill for specific modes
;; via hooks.  
(setq auto-fill-mode 1)

;;  Turn on visual line mode
(global-visual-line-mode t)

;; Prevent Emacs from making backup files
(setq make-backup-files nil)

;; Cleverref setup
(eval-after-load
    "latex"
  '(TeX-add-style-hook
    "cleveref"
    (lambda ()
      (if (boundp 'reftex-ref-style-alist)
      (add-to-list
       'reftex-ref-style-alist
       '("Cleveref" "cleveref"
         (("\\cref" ?c) ("\\Cref" ?C) ("\\cpageref" ?d) ("\\Cpageref" ?D)))))
      (add-to-list 'reftex-ref-style-default-list "Cleveref")
      (TeX-add-symbols
       '("cref" TeX-arg-ref)
       '("Cref" TeX-arg-ref)
       '("cpageref" TeX-arg-ref)
       '("Cpageref" TeX-arg-ref)))))

;; Latexmk setup
(defun run-latexmk ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((TeX-save-query nil)
        (TeX-process-asynchronous nil)
        (master-file (TeX-master-file)))
    (TeX-save-document "")
    (TeX-run-TeX "latexmk"
         (TeX-command-expand "latexmk -pdf %s" 'TeX-master-file)
                 master-file))
  (if (plist-get TeX-error-report-switches (intern master-file))
      (TeX-next-error t)
    (progn
      (demolish-tex-help)
      (minibuffer-message "latexmk: done."))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 
      (lambda ()
        (push 
         '("Latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
           :help "Run Latexmk on file")
         TeX-command-list)))

;; Set okular to open with C-c C-v view option 
(setq TeX-view-program-list
      '(("Okular" "okular --unique %u")))
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Okular")))

;; Paren checking
(load "paren")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/rainbow-delimiters-20150320.17")
(require 'rainbow-delimiters)
(global-rainbow-delimiters-mode)
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)

;; Adaptive wrap
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/adaptive-wrap-0.5")
(require 'adaptive-wrap)

(when (fboundp 'adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode)
  (defun my-activate-adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode ()
    "Toggle `visual-line-mode' and `adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode' simultaneously."
    (if visual-line-mode
        (adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode 1)
      (adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode -1)))
  (add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook 'my-activate-adaptive-wrap-prefix-mode))

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(TeX-PDF-mode t)
 '(TeX-newline-function (quote newline-and-indent))
 '(TeX-show-compilation t)
 '(TeX-source-correlate-method (quote synctex))
 '(TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
 '(TeX-view-program-list (quote (("Okular" "okular -unique %o#src:%n%b"))) t)
 '(TeX-view-program-selection (quote ((output-pdf "Okular"))) t)
 '(compilation-auto-jump-to-first-error t)
 '(inhibit-startup-screen t)
 '(ispell-lazy-highlight nil)
 '(server-mode t))
```

In my latexmkrc, I have

```
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %O %S
-file-line-error -synctex=1';
```

In my bash_aliases, I have the following

```
alias emacs='emacsclient -t -s server --alternate-editor='
alias ipython='ipython3'
```

Considering both set ups are identical running the same software, why wont this work on a different computer? I run into this problem every time I have to set back up emacs on any of my computers.

Messages received from `C-h e`:

```
Loading paren...done
Starting Emacs daemon.
File mode specification error: (void-function pushnew)
File local-variables error: (void-function pushnew)
When done with a buffer, type C-x #
```

Comment: You seem to be loading `auctex.el` in your init file. If the problem is related to the AucTex mode being absent, I'd start by trying to locate auctex.el, which I suspect is absent from another computer.

Comment: @dustin :) That screenshot clears things up. The string within the parentheses provide 3 sets of information.. it's not a single thing. (1) *Fundamental* mode is enabled (2) You opened that file using `emacsclient` and thus *Server* (3) You have `visual-line-mode` enabled and thus *Wrap*.

Comment: @dustin So what is it that's not working? Do the latex files always open in *Fundamental* mode?

Comment: @dustin After emacs starts up, the \*Messages\* log should have some errors. You can jump to that buffer directly using `C-h e`. Does that buffer list error or warning messages? If so, can you update your question with a list of those errors/warnings?

Comment: @wvxvw The `(load "auctex.el" nil t t)` has the [`NOERROR` argument](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/Fun/load) as `nil`. So Dustin should be seeing package loading errors if `auctex.el` (and `preview-latex.el`) are not found.

Comment: @kaushalmodi added messages

Comment: @dustin Can you re-start emacs using `emacs --debug-init` (after killing all servers/clients)  and paste the full error log that you see? Also what is your emacs version (`M-x emacs-version`)?

Comment: @kaushalmodi GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.8) of 2015-03-12 on\
 lcy01-03

Comment: @kaushalmodi it is complaining about rainbow delimiters. I checked `~/.emacs.d/elpa` and the load path is correct. I did have typo in the init file I pasted above but in the actually init it was correct.

Comment: Can you try putting `(require 'cl)` at the very beginning of your init? (though it should not be needed.) `pushnew` is defined in there. Also you shouldn't have to hardcode the path for each package. `(require 'package)` and `(package-initialize)` does that job for you automatically.

Comment: @kaushalmodi I made the change but didn't update the post. I will have to get back to you in a week since I am leaving in 8 mins.

Comment: @kaushalmodi `package-initialize` is autoloaded, so you don't even need to require it.

Comment: @Malabarba Yes, I need the require as I do `add-to-list` on `package-archives`. Without `(require 'package)`, I get `(void-variable package-archives)`. Discussions like these help me keep my emacs config updated with a crisp understanding of why I need each line in there :)

Comment: @kaushalmodi Do you call `package-initialize` in your configs? If so, you can call it before configuring the `package-archives` and then you don't need to `(require 'package)`. Not that it makes a difference, the end effect is the same. :-)

Comment: @Malabarba That's a great point. I was sticking to the idea to first finish with setting all the variables and then call the functions. Just like in `smart-mode-line`.. we first set the vars and then call `sml/setup`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be the issue:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/")
```

The packages in that directory don't necessarily come bundled with emacs, they're system-specific and they depend on how you install Emacs. So these packages might be present on one machine but absent from the other.

You should install AucTeX yourself.

- Call `M-x list-packages`.
- In that list install the Auctex package by hitting `i x`.

Comment: I use the cvs version off of github so I don't install it through the package manager. I am going to Georgia now so have to look at this later.

Comment: Also, this everything done was 100% identical to my other system  so it is odd it isn't working.

Comment: @dustin in that case, I recommend you remove all those lines you have which are configuring the load-path, they're doing more harm than good (and they could be the cause). Also remove the package-update-load-path function. Emacs should take care of all that stuff for you, just add `(package-initialize)` to the top of your init file.

Comment: Added information requested by kaushal

Comment: If you add `(load "paren")
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/rainbow-delimiters-20150320.17")
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'rainbow-delimiters-mode)`  this to your answer, I will be able to accept. I had to remove `(require 'rainbow-delimiters)
(global-rainbow-delimiters-mode)`

Comment: @dustin Don't use that add-to-list, use package-initialize instead.

Comment: You are saying replace add-to-list with package initialize in `(add-to-list 'package-archives 
         '("marmelade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives 
         '("elpa" . "http://tromey.com/elpa/"))`

Comment: @dustin No. I'll referring to the add-to-list you mentioned in your comment 5 minutes ago. Packages inside your Elpa directory are automatically added to the load-path when you call package-initialize.

Comment: Making that change produces `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (0 . 1) 2)
  package-initialize(load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/rainbow-delimiters-20150320.17")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/dustin/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3444` Also, autoindent stopped working when I use math in between `\[ \]` and for `\begin{cases}\end{cases}`

Comment: @dustin I wasn't clear. Forget about the previous comment. Just delete from your init file any lines that start with `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa/`. They are redundant at best, and harmful at worst.

Comment: Now I receive `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "adaptive-wrap")
  require(adaptive-wrap)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/dustin/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3610Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "adaptive-wrap")
  require(adaptive-wrap)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/dustin/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3610` in regards to adaptive wrap.

Comment: @dustin Do you still have that `(package-initialize)` line at the top of your file?

Comment: No  added characters

Comment: @dustin  Leave that line in. As long as you have that `(package-initialize)` you don't need to manually add Elpa packages to your load-path.

Comment: What should I have in the top part of the init file?

Comment: @dustin `(package-initialize)`